# How to call specific function based on speech recognition input from user in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

Is it possible to call a function based on the input received from user using speech recognition in python? I mean, if the user said a word like "add" then based on that input call add() function. Is it possible?

I have edited and added my complete code. It understands my input correctly, print it and then again starts listening without calling the specific functions. So now anyone can refer me how can I do it?

```
import pyttsx3
import datetime
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
import sys
import smtplib

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')

engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def wishme():

    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour >= 0 & hour < 12:
        speak("Good Morning!")

    elif hour>=12 and hour<18:
        speak("Good Afternoon!")

    else:
        speak("Good Afternoon!")

    speak("I am an AI Sir. Please tell me how may I help you")


def takecommand():
    # It takes microphone input from user

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening....")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing....")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'en-IN')
        print(f'User said: {query}\n')

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("Say that again please.....")
        speak("Say that again please")

        return "None"

    return query

def add(num1, num2):
c = num1 + num2
print(c)

def subs(num1, num2):
d = num1 - num2
print(d)

def multiply(num1, num2):
e = num1 * num2
print(e)

def divide(num1, num2):
f = num1 / num2
print(f)

if __name__ == '__main__':

wishme()
while True:
    query = takecommand().lower()

    if 'add' in query:
        add(2, 5)

    if 'substract' in query:
        subs(2, 5)

    if 'multiply' in query:
        multiply(2, 5)

    elif 'exit' in query:
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: yes, it is possible.

Comment: how can i do? can you please refer me ?

Comment: Your code seems to be doing exactly that.

Comment: but it isn't calling the function. Nothing is happening

Comment: first use `print()` to see what you get in query. Maybe system didn't recognize your words correctly.

Comment: @Galrikh Welcome to SO. You may want to read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly (well, if you expect some serious help I mean...). Oh and yes; _fix your code indentation_ - Python uses indentation as part of the syntax, so badly indented code is just meaningless.

Comment: If your code is not working as expected you should post a [mcve].

Comment: you have wrong indentations in code - it will not work.

Comment: @furas i am not getting any syntax error.

Comment: @Goyo i will do that if i don't get solution

Comment: maybe you have correct indentations in your editor/IDE but you put code with wrong indentations.

Comment: you are downvoted maybe because you didn't add code at start. But now people will not go back to you question to remove this downvote.

Comment: ok but i still didn't get how can i do it

Comment: I change indentations and I run your code and sometimes it recognize words and run function. I'm not sure if your problem can be indentations which can be catched by except and it doesn't run your code even if it recognized your word.

Comment: @furas The code does not reproduce the problem stated n the question.

Comment: @Goyo you are right.

Comment: while running this file there is an error install and import pyaudio

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but isn't as easily do able as you think it may be, you need speech recognition for this which in itself is a large problem. But if you want a very naive option you may use some package like

[SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/)

If you can get the string "add" from speech recognition then your code will work as it is.

Comment: yeah i am using speech recognition and i got that string from speech recognition

Comment: A very clear indication that your code is wrong is that even for `if 'substract' in query:` you `add(2,5)` thats a copy paste error, fix that, apart from that can you please share what error you are facing?

Comment: Also keep in mind, you have written `substract` not subtract

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Google Speech API.
I would recommend following tutorial series: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-AzGZ_CHzJk&t=333s